Why is there distortion on the output waveform when the inductor value is small but not when the inductor value is large?
I am experimenting with this amplifier:

Here is the output waveform when L is 1uH and emitter resistor is 2.2k.

Here is the output when the inductor is 222nH and the resistor is 600 ohms.

From a previous post, I saw that the gain of the waveform should be:
A = jwL/(RE+1/gm)
so i chose the inductor value so that it matches the emitter resistor to have a gain of 1 v/v. This is for the purpose of learning.

You should take more points ... for the curves.

what is happening with the gain? The emitter and collector impedances should be the same at 430 MHz.

The inductor value isn't the only thing you changed between the two simulations.

I also changed the emitter resistor. Everything else was the same.

is because It effects the bias operating point?

What are the values of resistors R2 & R3?  What is the internal series resistance of the inductor?  What voltage is Vcc?  What is the voltage waveform of V2?  What is the internal series impedance of V2?

Plot the collector current of the transistor.

The inductance isn't the only thing you changed. The emitter resistor was reduced between the first and second simulations.
The emitter resistor provides negative feedback to the circuit. By reducing its value you reduce the negative feedback.
The result is what you see: increased gain and increased distortion.

but i reduced the emitter resistor in proportion to how i reduced the inductor. The impedance of the collector and emitter should be the same. so the gain should be the same right? A = jwL/(RE+a/gm)

With a lower inductance (and similar resistors), the inductor current is higher. This leads to saturation (low VCE) of the transistor and since it cannot operate normally like that, the waveform gets distorted.
Your equation A = jwL/(RE+1/gm) only applies for a 'small' signal where gm remains constant. In large signal (where the transistor current changes by a significant percentage), the equation is less precise. This type of tradeoff and approximation is fundamental in electronics.
